# how to extract "value" from a table tag using class name with jsoup

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

When I try to extract value of tag using class name within Table tag, I get something like this:

```
<input class="TGNDateInput" type="text" name="txtDate" size="10" maxlength="10" value="2015/08/06">
```

Using jsoup, how can I extract just the date value ("2015/08/06")?

Here is my code:

```
System.out.println(table.getElementsByClass("criteriatext").get(1).getElementsByAttribute("value"));
```

Actual table on web page:

```
<table BORDER=0 WIDTH=40%>
<tr>
<td class=criteriatext>Date:</td>
<td class=criteriatext>
<input class=DateInput type=text name=txtDate SIZE=10 MAXLENGTH=10 VALUE="2015/08/05">
  &nbsp;<span class=textsmall>(yyyy/mm/dd)</span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should get it directly using selector:

```
Element txtDateInput = document.select("input[name=txtDate]").first();
String txtDate = txtDateInput.attr("value");
```

Comment: Thank you very much Nitesh for your help. Can you please also suggest how to get value if no "value" or "name" attributes are mentioned. like <p class=AsOfDate>
  As of&nbsp;&nbsp;2015 Aug 06 10:00:00
  </p> ...I need to extract "2015 Aug 06 10:00:00"

Comment: Use class selector to get the value

Comment: Like this doc.select("p.AsOfDate").text()

Comment: Thank you very much Nitesh. It works. I am hoping in p.class "p" is for para tag. Kindly correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

To get value of attribute from Element use `Element#attr("attributeName")` so in your case it could simply add it after your selector like:

```
String date = table.getElementsByClass("criteriatext")
                   .get(1)
                   .getElementsByAttribute("value")
                   .attr("value");

System.out.println(date);// -> 2015/08/05
```

You could probably also simply select `input` which is placed inside `td` of class `criteriatext` and have attribute `value` like

```
String date = table.select("td.criteriatext > input[value]").attr("value");
```